# Memory leak - periodically image download

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I make a code :

```
var camImage = camImage || {};
camImage.getImg = function() {
    var currDate = new Date(); 
    var image = null;
    var link = 'http://localhost/picture.php?rand='+currDate.valueOf();
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        success: function(){
            $('#camera img').eq(0).remove();
            image = $('<img />').attr('src', link);
            $('#camera').append(image);
            link = null;
            image = null;
            currDate = null;
        }
    });

};
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(camImage.getImg, 1000);
});
```

This simple code gets periodically new image and adding it to the DOM.
With each downloaded image browser memory usage increases. Is this code causes a memory leak?

Answer (score 4):

The Ajax request is unnecessary. Just setting the img src to a new URL will suffice:

```
camImage.getImg = function() {
    var src = 'http://localhost/picture.php?rand=' + (new Date()).valueOf();
    $('#camera img:first').detach().attr('src', src).appendTo('#camera');
}
```

I use `detatch()` instead of `remove()` since this keeps the original DOM element around for re-use.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the function did not give much:

```
camImage.getImg = function() {
  var src = 'http://localhost/picture.php?rand=' + (new Date()).valueOf();
  $('#camera img:first').detach().attr('src', src).appendTo('#camera');
}
```

Memory usage still increasing. This is due to memory leak in javascript or is there another reason?